# I see no effect on SpriteKit Rendering Performance on with using ignoresSiblingOrder and zPosition

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, performance, sprite-kit

In the SpriteKit documentation and also in the videos of the WWDC Apple advised to use the zPosition to increase the SpriteKit rendering performance.

I've tried to measure the effect. Unfortunately I cannot see any effect.

I've created a standard game project:
[image]

and replaced the *touchesBegan* method with this code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

// Determine the center of the view
CGPoint loc = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

// My expectation was that this has a huge defect on the FPS
self.view.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;


// Create thousands of sprites on different layers
for (int i=-25; i<=25; i++) {
    for (int j=-50; j<=50; j++) {

        // create a node to group the sprites
        SKNode *node = [[SKNode alloc] init];
        node.position = CGPointMake(loc.x+10*i, loc.y+10*j);
        node.zPosition=100;
        [self addChild:node];

        // Create sprites for layer 1
        SKSpriteNode *sprite1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
        sprite1.zRotation=0.0;
        sprite1.size=CGSizeMake(10, 10);
        if (self.view.ignoresSiblingOrder) sprite1.zPosition=1;
        [node addChild:sprite1];

        // Create sprites for layer 2
        SKSpriteNode *sprite2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
        sprite2.size=CGSizeMake(10, 10);
        sprite2.zRotation=0.75;
        if (self.view.ignoresSiblingOrder) sprite2.zPosition=2;
        [node addChild:sprite2];

        // Create sprites for layer 3
        SKSpriteNode *sprite3 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
        sprite3.size=CGSizeMake(10, 10);
        sprite3.zRotation=1.5;
        if (self.view.ignoresSiblingOrder) sprite3.zPosition=3;
        [node addChild:sprite3];

        // Create sprites for layer 4
        SKSpriteNode *sprite4 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
        sprite4.size=CGSizeMake(10, 10);
        sprite4.zRotation=2.2;
        if (self.view.ignoresSiblingOrder) sprite4.zPosition=4;
        [node addChild:sprite4];

        // Create sprites for layer 5
        SKSpriteNode *sprite5 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
        sprite5.size=CGSizeMake(10, 10);
        sprite5.zRotation=3.14;
        if (self.view.ignoresSiblingOrder) sprite5.zPosition=5;
        [node addChild:sprite5];

        // Add some animations
        SKAction *action = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI duration:1];
        [sprite1 runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:action]];
        [sprite2 runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:action]];
        [sprite3 runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:action]];
        [sprite4 runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:action]];
        [sprite5 runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:action]];

    }
}}
```

My expectation was to see a huge difference, between this two scenarios:

```
self.view.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;
```

and

```
self.view.ignoresSiblingOrder = NO;
```

But it differs only by one FPS.

[image]

Is the effect that low or have I done something wrong? I've tested on an iPhone 5 with iOS 8 Beta 4.

I know that this are way to many sprites for a real game on an iPhone. I've started with a small number of sprites, found no effect, increased the number of sprites, ...

Many thanks
Stefan

Considering the comment from LearnCocos2d I've changed the code for my test scenario. The sprites are bigger and 3 sprites per node are covering themselves completely.

Surprisingly self.view.ignoresSiblingOrder = NO is faster by 4 FPS. Now I'm really confused ...

Here's my new test code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

int iSpriteSize =100;

// Determine the center of the view
CGPoint loc = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

// My expectation was that this has a huge defect on the FPS
self.view.ignoresSiblingOrder = NO;


// Create thousands of sprites on different layers
for (int i=-5; i<=5; i++) {
    for (int j=-5; j<=5; j++) {

        // create a node to group the sprites
        SKNode *node = [[SKNode alloc] init];
        node.position = CGPointMake(loc.x+iSpriteSize*i, loc.y+iSpriteSize*j);
        node.zPosition=100;
        [self addChild:node];

        // Create sprites for layer 1
        SKSpriteNode *sprite1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
        sprite1.zRotation=0.0;
        sprite1.size=CGSizeMake(iSpriteSize, iSpriteSize);
        if (self.view.ignoresSiblingOrder) sprite1.zPosition=1;
        [node addChild:sprite1];

        // Create sprites for layer 2
        SKSpriteNode *sprite2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
        sprite2.size=CGSizeMake(iSpriteSize, iSpriteSize);
        sprite2.zRotation=0.0;
        if (self.view.ignoresSiblingOrder) sprite2.zPosition=2;
        [node addChild:sprite2];

        // Create sprites for layer 3
        SKSpriteNode *sprite3 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
        sprite3.size=CGSizeMake(iSpriteSize, iSpriteSize);
        sprite3.zRotation=0.0;
        if (self.view.ignoresSiblingOrder) sprite3.zPosition=3;
        [node addChild:sprite3];

        // Create sprites for layer 4
        SKSpriteNode *sprite4 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
        sprite4.size=CGSizeMake(iSpriteSize, iSpriteSize);
        sprite4.zRotation=2.2;
        if (self.view.ignoresSiblingOrder) sprite4.zPosition=4;
        [node addChild:sprite4];

        // Create sprites for layer 5
        SKSpriteNode *sprite5 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
        sprite5.size=CGSizeMake(iSpriteSize, iSpriteSize);
        sprite5.zRotation=3.14;
        if (self.view.ignoresSiblingOrder) sprite5.zPosition=5;
        [node addChild:sprite5];

        // Add some animations
        SKAction *action = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI duration:1];
        [sprite1 runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:action]];
        [sprite2 runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:action]];
        [sprite3 runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:action]];
        [sprite4 runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:action]];
        [sprite5 runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:action]];

    }
}}
```

Comment: Test with lesser nodes.

Comment: OK. My assumption was: more nodes => bigger effect? I'll try. Thanks

Comment: More nodes → worse performance, whether `ignoresSiblingOrder` is set or not.

Comment: Yes, but I want to have a worse performance to get an idea about how big the improvement with ignoresSiblingOrder is.

Comment: Realistically, you are never going to have 17506 nodes simultaneously, so don't get into that.

Comment: Considering how the iOS GPU works I imagine that the supposed effect comes from the GPU not drawing certain sprites if they are entirely or largely covered by other sprites in front of them. Also your test uses 10x10 sprites which is rather small size and the overhead of so many small sprites could diminish any benefits from z occlusion.

Comment: I've tried the following changes: increased the size of the sprite to 50. 3 Sprites are matching completely. The result is that ignoresSiblingOrder = NO is faster than ignoresSiblingOrder = YES?

Comment: My impression is that it allows SpriteKit to ignore drawing order of all sprites on the same zPosition. The performance improvement probably comes from not having to draw parents then children, etc in order on that z. To see the difference you might have to have a sprite with a few children on the same Z and compare YES/NO that way. In other words, when YES it doesn't care which is supposed to be drawn first.